# Backspace in python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x, backspace

Following python code is not giving me a `backspace` as it's supposed to.

```
var=('hel\b')
print(var)
```

Outputs:

```
hel
>>>
```

---

But setting terminal character as `nothing` works as expected.

```
var=('hel\b')
print(var,end='')
```

Outputs:

```
he>>>
```

---

In following example.

```
var=('hello\b\b \b')
print(var)
```

Outputs:

```
hel o
>>>
```

**What exactly is happening here ?**

Am coding in Python 3.5 in Notepad++. Os is Windows 7, 32-bit.

Comment: Backspaces are *never* carried over into next lines. A newline always moves the cursor into the next line and sets it back to the beginning of the line.

Comment: @poke That doesn't look like the case.

Comment: @iBug … because?

Comment: It's a python question. Why mark it duplicate with C question ? There could be different details even though previous question explains backspace behavior in C.

Comment: Because the behavior of the `\b` backspace sequence is the same. The explanations in the answers there (which have nothing to do with C btw) work in the same way. – *“There could be different details”*, but there aren’t. In the same way this question was not specific to Python *3*.

Answer (score 2):

The backspace character **`\b` only moves the cursor one character backwards, but never deletes or overwrites anything**.

In your second example, you should be able to observe it precisely: the Python prompt `>>>` has overwritten the last character, `l`.

If you had written `print('hel', end='')`, you would have seen:

```
hel>>>
```

The `\b` character shifted the cursor one character backwards, which made the prompt started printing at `l`, instead of after `l`.

If you want it to erase a character, **fill it with a space, then backshift again**:

```
>>> print('hel\b \b')
he
>>>
```

Comment: No ned to “backshift again” in the final example, only if you want subsequent output (on the same line) overwrite that cleared character too.

Comment: @poke Just in case.

Comment: putting nul-character (`'\x00'`) is also a thing to consider

Comment: @Superior: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/account_problems.png